# Membros estáticos String

Tags: c++, string, orientação-a-objetos, classes, static

Estou tentando criar um membro estático numa classe para que não precise instanciar a classe para se obter o valor da mesma.

Nos exemplos que achei na internet faz referencias a membros `int`.

No meu caso quero que o membro estático seja uma `string`.

Se eu fizer o seguinte:

```
class algumacoisa
{

public:
 algumacoisa();
~algumacoisa();

string texto;
static string recebetexto;

};

texto = "alguma frase aqui...";
string algumacoisa::recebetexto = texto;
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token

É só para exemplificar que se atribuir uma variável string normal a uma variável string estática ocorre o erro descrito. O cógido não está completo, mas dá para ter uma ideia do que se refere.

Comment: Coloque o código que está fazendo, até porque a explicação está confusa.

Comment: Formate o código melhor. Não consegui nem entender para poder formatar sua pergunta.

Comment: Que código é esse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplos feitos de qualquer jeito pode ter todo tipo de problema. Fiz um direitinho e não tem problema algum.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AlgumaClasse {

public:
    static string recebetexto;
};

string AlgumaClasse::recebetexto = "alguma frase aqui...";

int main() {
    cout << AlgumaClasse::recebetexto;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ufe1Fu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cnsurkbc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/StaticMember.cpp).

Comment: Bigown, Desse Jeito funciona.
Mas se a frase estiver em uma outra variavel que não é estatica e você tentar atribuir essa variavel a uma variavel estatica ocorre um erro.

Comment: Mas @L.Hora, uma variável não-estática não pode ser atribuída a uma estática pela própria natureza de ser estática. Além disso, você pode, por favor, editar a pergunta com a versão atualizada do seu código já usando a sugestão do do bigown.

Comment: Olá Pablo,
Eu consegui resolver a questão da atribuição de uma string não estática para uma estática. Criei uma função estatica que recebe uma string como argumento e dentro dessa função consegui atribuir esse argumento a uma string estática.